# What possible exceptions are there if User enters String instead of Int?

Tags: java, error-handling

I am just playing with Java.I'm trying to force my program to only accept number digits 1 and 2. I believe I have successfully done this using a while loop (please correct me if I'm wrong). But how do I go about printing an error statement if the user enters a string. eg: "abc".

My code:

```
    while (response != 1 && response != 2) {
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 for Car or 2 for Van: ");
        response = scan.nextInt();
    }

    if (response == 1) {
        vehicleType = VehicleType.CAR;
        while (numPassengerSeats < 4 || numPassengerSeats > 7) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of Passengers: ");
            numPassengerSeats = scan.nextInt();
        }
    } else {
        vehicleType = VehicleType.VAN;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the last maintenance date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
            String formattedDate = scan.next();
            lastMaintenanceDate = formatDate(formattedDate);
            if (lastMaintenanceDate != null)
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) of `java.util.Scanner.nextInt()` explains what exceptions it will throw under what circumstances. If you enter something that is not an integer, you'll get an `InputMismatchException`. You'll have to put your `nextInt()` statements in a try-block, and then catch the exception and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) for `nextInt()`:

> Scans the next token of the input as an int. An invocation of this
>   method of the form nextInt() behaves in exactly the same way as the
>   invocation nextInt(radix), where radix is the default radix of this
>   scanner.
>
> **Returns**: the int scanned from the input
>
> **Throws**:
>
> InputMismatchException
>   - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
>
> NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
>
> IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

As per javadoc, it throws `InputMismatchException` if the user enters a `String` instead of an `int`. So, we need to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have not successfully force your program to accept just integers since by using `java.util.Scanner.nextInt()`, user can still be able to input non integers, however `java.util.Scanner.nextInt()` will just throw an exception. Refer to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) for possible exception thrown.
I have made a solution to force your program to accept just integers. Just follow the sample code below:

Sample code:

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int response = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (response != 1 && response != 2) {
            System.out.println("Please enter 1 for Car or 2 for Van: ");
            try {
                response = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine()); 
                if (response != 1 && response != 2) {
                    System.out.println("Input is not in choices!");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Input is invalid!");
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't 'accept' and 'throw an exception' at the same time.

Comment: @user207421 It seems you misunderstood my answer, my mistake for not explaining it well. What I mean't that user can still input non-integers and the program will throw an exception. I have modified my answer. If there are still mistakes kindly comment it so that I can update/delete it if ever. Thanks for the comment!